# How to remove duplicated rows from data frame in R

Tags: r

How could I remove duplicated rows from data frame

```
  Area    Population
GOMBAK       668,694
GOMBAK       668,694
GOMBAK       668,694
  Batu       285,288
  Batu       285,288
 KLANG       842,146
 KLANG       842,146
```

to be

```
GOMBAK    668,694
  Batu    285,288 
 KLANG     842,14
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I've tried this   MK <- sqldf('SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Muki_Sela')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `duplicated()` function:

```
df <- data.frame(Area=c("GOMBAK", "GOMBAK", "GOMBAK", "Batu", "Batu", "KLANG", "KLANG"),
                 Population=c(668694, 668694, 668694, 285288, 285288, 842146, 842146))
df <- df[!duplicated(df), ]

> df
    Area Population
1 GOMBAK     668694
4   Batu     285288
6  KLANG     842146
```

If you want to compute the sum of the population, then the following should work:

```
sum(as.numeric(levels(df$Population)))
```

It is necessary to work with `levels` because your population column is a `factor`, based on what you mentioned in the comment.

Comment: yes it dose   thank you, any idea how to sum population column ?? i need the total   sorry but  i am new in R

Comment: Thank you bro 

I've got this error 
Error in Summary.factor(c(124L, 77L, 49L, 135L, 26L, 144L, 23L, 75L, 113L,  : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: yes correct it is a factor

  Thank you very much

Comment: Why not just `unique( df )`?

Answer (score 0):

```
sqldf('SELECT DISTINCT * FROM df')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% distinct
```